# declaring variable inside and outside of ready function

Tags: jquery, performance

I was using jQuery something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var timer;
    $(selector).on('click',function(){
        //some functions
    });
    ....
    $(element).on('click',function(){
        // some functions
        clearInterval(timer);
        timer = setInterval(function(){
            //some functions here
        });
    });
});
```

And the `$(element)` click function was triggering multiple times unexpectedly and also browser hang problem. But later I solved the issue by shifting declaration of the variable timer outside ready function like this:

```
var timer;
$(document).ready(function(){
....
}
```

**Question:**  how the variable works inside ready and outside ready function?

---

Here is the full jquery code I have used: http://jsfiddle.net/CG9Yn/

Comment: With the code you show (I mean, probably, as it's not indented it's hard to tell), there's no reason to be a difference.

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem in a fiddle ?

Comment: live site http://kldugargroup.com/dugar-gallery

Comment: if you click next button repeatedly then browser will hang but if place timer outside ready then it works fine.

Comment: This would only make sense if `$(document).ready()` gets called multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

**ANSER BEFORE THE FIDDLE**
If you define `var timer` inside the function then every time its a new timer. For example

```
var timer; // assuming you declared it here
clearInterval(timer);
 timer = setInterval(function(){
            //some functions here
 });
```

In the above code in every click old timer will be not cleared and every time a new timer will be created and `clearInterval(timer);` will not have any effect. Which is fixed by defining `timer` outside the function, now in every click the previous timer is cleared first and then a new timer is created.

Does this answer your question?

**UPDATE**

In your fiddle inside "`$(document).on('click','.play',function(){`" you have not called "`clearInterval`". Is that fine? I think you should add that. Also can you paste the html so that the fiddle runs

Comment: If you have defined the timer in the place where I am showing in my code. Do you think clearInterval will clear the old timer, I mean from previous click?

Comment: I couldn't understand what you are saying.

Comment: Ok. When you was getting the hang issue did you coded the same way I have shown in my post? I mean did you defined the "timer" just like I have shown in my code?

Comment: please see the jsfiddle in my question.

Comment: in your fiddle inside "$(document).on('click','.play',function(){" you have not called "clearInterval". Is that fine? I think you should add that. Also can you paste the html so that the fiddle runs.

Answer (score 0):

The variable works the same actually. The only difference is the access (local or global). Performance are the same.

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of where you put the declaration, looking at the following code:

```
$(document).on('click','.play',function(){
    $(this).removeClass('play').addClass('pause');
    timer = setInterval(function(){
        $('.gallery-wrapper .next').click();
    }, 5000);

});
```

As you can see, the `setInterval()` is performed unconditionally, which means that if there was an existing timer, it would now get overwritten, so only the last timer can be stopped.

Adding a `clearInterval(timer)` before doing another `setInterval()` should help, though perhaps you should use `setTimeout()` instead so that your code is triggered at most one time.